# Java android studio error get firebase database to MyClass

Tags: java

I have a class of variables, I send the class to a database and cannot restore back.

MyClass:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class StringTravel implements Serializable {

    @PropertyName("d_citylocation_p1")
    public double getD_citylocation_p1() {
        return d_citylocation_p1;
    }
    @PropertyName("d_citylocation_p1")
    public void setD_citylocation_p1(double d_citylocation_p1) {
        this.d_citylocation_p1 = d_citylocation_p1;
    }

    @PropertyName("d_citylocation_p2")
    public double getD_citylocation_p2() {
        return d_citylocation_p2;
    }

    @PropertyName("d_citylocation_p2")
    public void setD_citylocation_p2(double d_citylocation_p2) {
        this.d_citylocation_p2 = d_citylocation_p2;
    }

    @PropertyName("str_status_sortD")
    public String getStr_status_sortD() {
        return str_status_sortD;
    }

    @PropertyName("str_status_sortD")
    public void setStr_status_sortD(String str_status_sortD) {
        this.str_status_sortD = str_status_sortD;
    }

    public double d_citylocation_p1;
    public double d_citylocation_p2;
    public String str_status_sortD;

    @PropertyName("phone_driver")
    public String getPhone_driver() {
        return phone_driver;
    }

    @PropertyName("phone_driver")
    public void setPhone_driver(String phone_driver) {
        this.phone_driver = phone_driver;
    }

    public String phone_driver;


    @PropertyName("str_name_t")
    public String getStr_name_t() {
        return str_name_t;
    }

    @PropertyName("str_name_t")
    public void setStr_name_t(String str_name_t) {
        this.str_name_t = str_name_t;
    }

    public String str_name_t;
}
```

get data to class:

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers").child(phone);
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot2 : snapshot1.child("orders").getChildren()){
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot3 : snapshot2.getChildren()){
                                if (snapshot3.exists()) {
                                    assert stringTravel != null;
                                    stringTravel = snapshot3.getValue(StringTravel.class);

//                                    if (stringTravel!=null)
//                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), stringTravel.getStr_name_t(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

The error that returns me is: "Cauldnt convert type to "MyClass
this exeption:

```
     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.ranasd.wears.bottombarClick.ClassStringTravel.StringTravel
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:202)
        at com.ran.nework.driver.bottombarClick.OrderDriver$1.onDataChange(OrderDriver.java:139)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

I checked the class and the database carefully and I saw that they match and are arranged in order and still returns an error.

```
orders{
jrDe288VQFgiuCTd85Tmk1WUn{
d_citylocation_p1:
20.5545
d_citylocation_p2:
45.5488
str_city1
:
"yesoo"
str_city2
:
"govi"
str_name_t
:
"vior"
phone_driver
:
"51384555757"
str_rand
:
"jrDe288VQFgiuCTd85Tmk1WUn"
str_status_sortD
:
"car"
}
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening?

Comment: stringTravel = snapshot3.getValue(StringTravel.class);

Comment: I recommend you use a debugger and step through the code to see what are the actual values

Comment: My minute I did everything and the values are displayed as the one I sent. As if the problem is because it's a class and doesn't change and I don't understand what it has

Comment: I checked again and it always crashes in the first variable of the class no matter which variable

Comment: hear?
I tried to enter one by one with each one's setter and now it doesn't crash. Something is wrong and I don't understand what